# Cannot find protocol declaration MKAnnotation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mkannotation

The code is:

```
@interface RouteMapAnnotation : NSObject <MKAnnotation> 
{    
    CLLocationCoordinate2D  coordinate;
    NSString*               title;
    NSString*               subtitle;
}

@property (nonatomic, readonly) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString* title;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString* subtitle;

@end
```

Here's a snapshot of the error I have:

https://skitch.com/kuntul/rws3c/smartrek-routemapannotation.h

What is wrong? I've done this on the same exact project and it works..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Did you remember to `#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>`?

Comment: weird in my other project I didn't have to do this and it compiled just fine

Comment: Did you have it in your `.pch` file for that project, or in another header that you happened to include?

Answer (score 2):

have you imported MKAnnotation.h ?

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to `#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>`.

There really is no other reason why this would come up.

Answer (score 0):

Just insert One line

**#import < MapKit/MapKit.h>**